# What does "feedback vendors" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> As somebody who has reviewed almost all feedback vendors on the market, I would absolutely recommend Usabilla to anybody looking to collect onsite feedback.

Does *feedback vendors* mean a vendor who sells feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard the term before. If you google ["Feedback Vendor"](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&espv=2&q=%22feedback+vendor%22&oq=%22feedback+vendor%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i7i30j0i8i30l9.6155.7030.0.7618.2.2.0.0.0.0.140.250.0j2.2.0.msedr...0...1c.1.62.serp..0.2.249.DQBUNCJTAOA) (With the quotes) there are only 3,420 results, as opposed to [Feedback Vendor](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&espv=2&q=feedback%20vendor&oq=feedback%20vendor&gs_l=serp.3..0i7i30j0i5i30l3j0i8i30l6.94671.95465.0.95737.2.2.0.0.0.0.217.385.0j1j1.2.0.msedr...0...1c.1.62.serp..0.2.383.hoU6VCD3qs4), (Without the quotes) which has 91.7 million results. This must be a very obscure term, or even a mistake. However, googling "Usabilla" brought me to [this website](https://usabilla.com/), which seems to be exactly what you have described, a vendor that sells feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Feedback is an advice, criticism or information about how good or useful something or somebody's work is.

As somebody who has reviewed almost all feedback vendors on the market, I would absolutely recommend Usabilla to anybody looking to collect onsite feedback.

> This person's work is read all the **vendor's
>   information/criticism/advices** (or feedbacks) about the market.   And he gives a
>   recomendation to look their information in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

The vendor sells software or a service to help a company collect feedback (comments from site visitors) "onsite" , and to analyze and/or respond to it.